# java default locale don't working appropriately in Linux OS?

Tags: java, linux, locale

In Java code running on a linux system, my default locale getting from Locale.getDefault() is en_US however when using Scanner nextDouble() decimal separator appears to be a comma instead of a period. What's happening?

Comment: Check your locale from `scannerVar.locale()` (e.g. `new Scanner(System.in).locale()`) and see what this returns.

Comment: In addition to what Tom says (assuming that doesn't help), you should create and post an SSCCE and show us what your code looks like in case you are unknowingly shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @Tom you hit a home run,  the result from myScannerVar.locale() is pt_BR different from Locale.getDefault() en_US,  my question is why?

Comment: I wouldn't spent much time in that. Just set the locale in scanner which you want to use to fix the issue. Different locals can have different reasons, for example your locale is pt_BR when creating the Scanner, but something else sets it to en_US.